# Linux disable ssh ChallengeResponse for one user

Tags: linux, ssh, pam, two-factor-authentication, challenge-response

I just installd libpam-yubico to use my Yubikey 4 to login in ssh (Debian 8).
My problem is that i can't connect with my mobile phone because my Yubikey 4 can't be used from a mobile. Same problem for my SFTP connection.
So what I want to do is: Create an user who only have to type password and who doesn't have to use Yubikey.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `/etc/pam.d/login` file? (make sure there's no sensitive data in it first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if before calling libpam-yubico.

Reading [this Yubikey documentation](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-pam/Yubikey_and_SSH_via_PAM.html) I suppose that you added a rule in your pam config file. Right before that line, you can try something like this:

`auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid = 500`

Of course, you have to replace 500 with the actual user id.

Comment: @TriiNoxYs I just updated my answer, you can try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Ty, it works !
I tried this but with "user = mobile" instead of using the uid ..
Ty !

Comment: Please make sure you still have to type a password to be able to log in with this account, leaving a backdoor behind you is a common mistake when editing pam rules.

Comment: Yep, I still have to type my password